# ubuntu server 12.04 can not remove dhcp-client

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

When I change network from dhcp to static, it will periodically change IP to the dhcp configuration and ignore the configuration of /etc/network/interface.

So I want to remove the dhcp-client, however when I remove it in Ubuntu, I encounter this problem. Can you give me some help ?

```
$ sudo apt-get remove dhcp-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**Virtual packages like 'dhcp-client' can't be removed**
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
```

this is my interface file content:

```
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: Can you post your /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: i have post my interface file

Comment: See my answer below to update the interfaces file

Comment: I've seen this on a bunch of systems I was in the process of setting up recently after manually editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and restarting networking, I kept seeing hosts disappear. As I hadn't commissioned the systems, I was able to reboot them, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never had Ubuntu behave like this, so this is just a wild guess: It could have something to do with 'network-manager'.

As to the removal of dhcp-client:

You are trying to remove a virtual package. Virtual packages don't really exist they are just provided by some packages to declare they provide a similar service/function (see also [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual_pkg)).
IIRC the default dhcp-client package installed by ubuntu is 'isc-dhcp-client', but no mater which one is installed on your system you probably will have a rather hard time removing it cleanly as quite some other packages depend on it being installed.

Comment: actually, what you have said is right, i can remove isc-dhcp-client from my ubuntu, and i learn about what is virtual package, thank you! I will see whether if dhcp-client cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't take the interface down before reconfiguring it, and so there is still a DHCP client running in the background trying to maintain the DHCP IP. Check for this with `ps -eF | grep dhclient` and kill the process.

If you really want to uninstall the DHCP client (which you shouldn't need to), you need to remove the `dhcp3-client` package.

Comment: when i type this in terminal : ps -eF | grep dhclient.    it shows nothing, and i also sudo apt-get remove dhcp3-client, it shows that i did not install it any more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the isc-dhcp-client completely. If  DNS-server addresses are configured both in the isc-dhcp-client and in `/etc/network/interfaces` file the addresses in the client configuration always take precedence and will be the ones that are written to `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you want the dns-servers setting in `/etc/network/interfaces` to be written to `/etc/resolv.conf` you will have to remove the isc-dhcp-client completely.

The `apt-get --purge remove isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common` command will do just that. 
If that does not do the trick find and remove these two files:

`/run/resolvconf/interface/eth0.dhclient` and `/run/resolvconf/interface/original.resolvconf`

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem line,

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Remove it and restart your networking.

```
$ sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: i am sorry, i have lost #, it was commented in interface file. when copy from file, i lost it.

Comment: This is ineffective in `12.04` or `12.10`. As mgorven pointed out, dhclient is still running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. My not so scientific test found this solution. Put network and broadcast in interace config too. Like this:

```
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.7
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```